# How to add background images to a ListView

Tags: android, listview, design-patterns, android-listview

I noticed that the Secret app lets users add custom images as background layouts for list items in a list view.

How is this effect achievable?

[image]

Comment: Just create a custom adapter. In this adapter, you will be able to provide any view or custom view, with ImageView or whatever you want.

Comment: maybe they save it somewhere in the phone directory and then access them programmatically and set it as background?

Comment: Just change the background image of your custom rows.